# Maven Repository Manager Package

Tags: maven-3

Is there any package for a Maven repository manager? I searched for some of the ones I know, but couldn't find any. I'm wondering if they are just not available, if they have names different than what I searched for, or, perhaps, if there's some I may have missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.4-M4-SNAPSHOT/adminguide/standalone.html

If you use Puppet to manage your infrastructure, you can use a third-party Puppet module to install Archiva. This will take care of adding the required users, databases and configuration based on official release tarballs.

https://forge.puppetlabs.com/maestrodev/archiva

Answer (score 1):

I don't know know of any Maven repository managers packaged for Ubuntu, but [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/) and possibly others can certainly be deployed on Ubuntu.

Download the standalone version and extract it:

```
wget http://apache.osuosl.org//archiva/binaries/apache-archiva-1.3.5-bin.tar.gz
tar -xvzf apache-archiva-1.3.5-bin.tar.gz
```

To start it run:

```
./apache-archiva-1.3.5/bin/archiva start
```

It should then be available at http://localhost:8080/archiva

More advance documentation can be found in the [System Administrators Guide to Apache Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.3.5/adminguide/index.html).

Comment: Yes, of course, but it isn't a package. I can't write `package { 'archiva': ensure => installed }` in my Puppet configuration to tell it how to build a maven repo server.